# retrieving the following line using python next() and strip()

Tags: python, iterator, line, strip

I'm having trouble using `next()` and `strip()` to retrieve the line following the one I'm reading. The test data looks something like this:

```
@abcde:111/2
ABCDEFGHIj
+abcde:111/2
bla11
@abcde:115/2
JDIJSKNDIJ
+abcde:115/2
bla13
@abcde:113/2
djijwkoken
+abcde:113/2
bla15
```

My goal is to delete all sets of 4 lines starting with '@' that contain 'N' in the second line. The expected test output should look like this:

```
@abcde:111/2
ABCDEFGHIj
+abcde:111/2
bla11
@abcde:113/2
djijwkoken
+abcde:113/2
bla15
```

Here is my code (delete_N.py), I'm running it using Mac OS Terminal on a remote Ubuntu server, with python 2.7:

```
import sys

filename1 = sys.argv[1] #file to process

data = open(filename1, 'r')

def del_N(input1):
    for line in input1:
        if line[:1] == '@' and 'N' not in next(input1).strip():
            print line.strip()
            for i in range(3):
                print next(input1).strip()

del_N(data)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "delete_N.py", line 14, in <module>
    del_N(data)
  File "delete_N.py", line 12, in del_N
    print next(input1).strip()
StopIteration
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program, you are over reading data from the file. Check [Lego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21128395/1903116), where he explains the mistake very clearly.

You can do it like this. This program assumes that the number of lines in the file is a multiple of 4.

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as input_file:
    for line1 in input_file:
        line2, line3, line4 = [next(input_file) for _ in xrange(3)]
        if "N" not in line2:
            print line1 + line2 + line3 + line4.rstrip()
```

**Output**

```
@abcde:111/2
ABCDEFGHIj
+abcde:111/2
bla11
@abcde:113/2
djijwkoken
+abcde:113/2
bla15
```

Answer (score 2):

Python raises a `StopIteration` exception when you reach the end of an iterator. If you're calling `next()` on an iterator manually, rather than using a `for ... in ...` loop (which will terminate when `StopIteration` is raised), you *must* catch `StopIteration` and handle it, because it means that... well, the iterator has stopped.

---

Anyway, here is a (IMO) cleaner solution:

```
data = ... # your data goes here, from a file or whatever
lines = data.split('\n')
n = 4
groups = zip(*[lines[i::n] for i in range(n)])
# or, groups = zip(lines[0::4], lines[1::4], lines[2::4], lines[3::4])
result = []

for group in groups:
    if group[0].startswith('@') and 'N' in group[1]:
        continue # i.e. don't append
    else:
        result.append(group)

joined_result = '\n'.join(['\n'.join(group) for group in result])
print(joined_result)
```

Result:

```
@abcde:111/2
ABCDEFGHIj
+abcde:111/2
bla11
@abcde:113/2
djijwkoken
+abcde:113/2
bla15
```

Comment: I usually use `continue` where you used `pass`.  `continue` will work no matter what the rest of the loop looks like.  In this case, the rest of the loop is an `else:` case so `pass` works.  Anyway, I agree this is the way to go rather than using `next()`.

Comment: @steveha Good point, `continue` is indeed stylistically better here. Will fix.

Comment: @steveha Why is `continue` better than `pass` or `next()`? I mean, in what situations would the loop not work?

Comment: `continue` stops executing the whole rest of the loop body.  It basically means "we're done here, move on to the next one".  You can use an `if` statement instead, putting what you want done in the `else`, and it will work just fine... but it is IMHO less clear.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that at the same time as you are iterating through the file with the `for` loop, `next` also iterates the cursor as it moves through the file. This means for each iteration you are actually jumping *3* spots at a time.

For example, look at this file:

```
                openning the file
@abcde:111/2    for line in input1: # First iteration.
ABCDEFGHIj          if line[:1] == '@' and 'N' not in next(input1).strip():
+abcde:111/2            print next(input1).strip()
bla11           for line in input1: # Second iteration.
@abcde:115/2       etc...
```

See how on each iteration up to 3 lines are jumped, so when the second last or last lines in the iteration are encountered, it will overflow and raise the `StopIteration` error.